# Added div is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This piece adds a dropdown to my html, script makes it selectable. i am trying to append that when I hit the add button. It append but not selectable anymore:

```
                    <div class="row noMargin topPadding">
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-2 " id="">
                            Correct Answer:
                        </div>
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Answer<span class="caret"></span></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Option1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Option2</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Option3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Option4</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>


                <div class="row noMargin topPadding">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default addQna" id="addQna">
                        Add
                </button>
            </div>
```

Here is the script. I tried to assign id to dropdown but no luck:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var currentItem = 1;
            $('#addQna').click(function(){
                currentItem++;
                $('#items').val(currentItem);
                var strToAdd ='<div class="row noMargin topPadding" id="question1"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-4  " id=""><input type="text" class="qnaQ form-control" id="qnaQ"></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-2  " id="">  <input type="text" class="qnaOpt1 form-control" id="qnaOpt1"></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-2  " id=""><input type="text" class="qnaOpt2 form-control" id="qnaOpt2"></div> <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-2  " id=""><input type="text" class="qnaOpt3 form-control" id="qnaOpt2"></div><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-2  " id=""><input type="text" class="qnaOpt4 form-control" id="qnaOpt4"></div><div class="row noMargin topPadding"><div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-1 col-md-2 " id="">Correct Answer:</div><div class="btn-group"><a class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Answer<span class="caret"></span></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a href="#">Option1</a></li><li><a href="#">Option2</a></li><li><a href="#">Option3</a></li><li><a href="#">Option4</a></li></ul></div></div></div>';

                $('#questions').append(strToAdd);

            });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
    var selText = $(this).text();
    $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText+' <span class="caret"></span>');
    });
</script>
```

Comment: why don't you make a jsfiddle out of this so its easier to test/update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this:

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(){
    var selText = $(this).text();
    $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText+' <span class="caret"></span>');
    });
```

to this:

```
$('body').on('click', ".dropdown-menu li a", function(){
    var selText = $(this).text();
    $(this).parents('.btn-group').find('.dropdown-toggle').html(selText+' <span class="caret"></span>');
    });
```

and try again. since you're appending new html, the click event handler won't work the way you have it. but try my suggestion it should work

heres a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s9an4zet/